# Change the template for a file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I create a new Unit test in Visual Studio, I always have a few things I do to the standard template.

It would be nice when I create the file to have those things done already.

Is there a way to modify the template so that when I select Add->New Nest->Unit Test, it will create a file with my modifications already done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's a hack. You have to edit the class template files that Visual Studio uses when it creates the file, which reside deep within the Program Files folder. [This article](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToEditVSTemplates.aspx) will tell you how.